# Authorize.net CIM SOAP API getCustomerPaymentProfile error

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I have implemented Authorize.net CIM API for my custom solution. Everything was working fine before.

Now when I trying to load any customer information with customer profile id and customer paymen profile id using SOP API of Authorize.net CIM it is getting failed.

I am getting following error "SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'unmaskExpirationDate' property" when trying using "getCustomerPaymentProfile" function of Authorize.net CIM API via merchant sandbox mode.

While with XML API for Authorize.net CIM of "getCustomerPaymentProfile" function returning ferfect but this error is only with SOAP API.

Below is the SOAP urls that I am using for sandbox account,

Gateway WSDL: "https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx?WSDL"

Test Gateway Url: "https://apitest.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx"

Have anybody faced such issue recently?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I got an answer just now.

When checking WSDL url I found that they have recently changed the WSDL xml format for "getCustomerPaymentProfile" function by adding Additional

"" which always expact the "unmaskExpirationDate" parameter as boolean as part of request parameters.

After updating my SOAP request parameters solved the error.

Comment: Using a Magento plugin for saving billing via Authorize.net CIM.  Payment still worked but using saved data was throwing this error.  Add this field to the soap call and problem solved.  Thanks for posting the solution.